# Get web response for other pages of the same application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, web

In an MVC web application, I have a page that should make a request to another page of the same application.

For example, when I access `http://localhost:1010/MyApp/Troubleshoot.aspx`, this page will make a web request to `http://localhost:1010/MyApp/Test` which will redirect to a login page. I would like to get the response of this call to get the Http response and perform validation.

Below is the code that I use (in Troubleshoot.aspx.cs):

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(@"http://localhost:1010/MyApp/Test");
using (var response = request.GetResponse())
{
    // Do validation on response
}
```

Code in TestController.cs:

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    public string Index()
    {
        return "Testing";
    }
}
```

The `request.GetResponse()` only returns `The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.` which gives no further information, making it hard to determine the failing reason.

The link `http://localhost:1010/MyApp/Test` return status 200 if access using browser with display text "Testing".

The same code also works fine with other links that are not pointing to its own application.

I even tried using `WebClient` and I achieved the same result. What am I missing here?

Comment: why not do request to login page directly? can you provide route and action for this url `http://localhost:1010/MyApp/`?

Comment: This is an MVC application and the link `http://localhost:1010/MyApp/` will call HomeController's Index() method. It will then redirect the page to 3rd party SSO page. The Troubleshoot.aspx helps me to check if the redirecting is calling to correct URL. It contains many other checkings as well.

Comment: can you provide code for _HomeController's Index() method_? also do you try set breakpoint in this action and see what's going on?

Comment: It never hit the breakpoint of the Index() action to begin with.....

Comment: are you sure that for this url `http://localhost:1010/MyApp` should run `Home/Index`? `request.GetResponse()` return some value or rise exception?

Comment: I checked it using browser and it works fine. It raise web exception once it's not status 200.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59323/discussion-between-grundy-and-cruellays).

Comment: can you provide exception text? and possibly InnerException message?